# PL/SQL update several table using select values as a table name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

may i ask..

im about to update several tables..
i was insert the list of table that i want to update..

here is the query :

```
insert into dgtmp_nama_tbl
select 'dgtmp_nf_vpnip_upd' from dual
union
select 'dgtmp_nf_metroe_upd' from dual
union
select 'dgtmp_nf_astinet_upd' from dual
union
select 'dgtmp_nf_iptransit_upd' from dual
union
select 'dgtmp_nf_cndc_upd' from dual
union
select 'dgtmp_nf_sdwan_upd' from dual
union
select 'dgtmp_nf_slwdm_upd' from dual
union
select 'dgtmp_nf_sldigital_upd' from dual
union
select 'dgtmp_nf_neulayer_upd' from dual
union
select 'dgtmp_nf_neu_intconnect_upd' from dual
```

then i update the tables with pl/sql.. but it return an error like this :

SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 8, column 12:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 8, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

here is my pl/sql script :

```
declare
    cursor c_list_tbl
    is
    select nama_tbl from dgtmp_nama_tbl;
begin
    for i in c_list_tbl
    loop
        update i.nama_tbl a
        set a.divisi = ( select a.divisi from rmart_accnum_all_divisi_2023 b where a.account_num = b.account_num ),
        a.segmen = ( select a.segmen from rmart_accnum_all_divisi_2023 b where a.account_num = b.account_num );
    commit;
    end loop;
end;
```

can anyone please check what's wrong with it?
sorry for my bad english, i hope u guys can understand what im saying..

thanks in advance..

i've tested it and return an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need **dynamic SQL** to do that.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c_list_tbl IS SELECT nama_tbl FROM dgtmp_nama_tbl;

   l_str  VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN c_list_tbl
   LOOP
      l_str := 'UPDATE ' || i.nama_tbl || ' a
         SET a.divisi =
                (SELECT b.divisi
                   FROM rmart_accnum_all_divisi_2023 b
                  WHERE a.account_num = b.account_num),
             a.segmen =
                (SELECT b.segmen
                   FROM rmart_accnum_all_divisi_2023 b
                  WHERE a.account_num = b.account_num)';

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic SQL (and should sanitise your user inputs):

```sql
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (select nama_tbl from dgtmp_nama_tbl) LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'MERGE INTO ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(i.nama_tbl) || ' dst
        USING (
          SELECT account_num
          FROM   rmart_accnum_all_divisi_2023
        ) src
        ON (src.account_num = dst.account_num)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE
          SET divisi = dst.divisi,
              segmen = dst.segmen';
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

However, you are updating the values to the same value. I think your code should be (and could include error handling):

```sql
DECLARE
  table_does_not_exist EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_does_not_exist, -942);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (select nama_tbl from dgtmp_nama_tbl) LOOP
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'MERGE INTO ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(i.nama_tbl) || ' dst
          USING (
            SELECT account_num,
                   divisi,
                   segmen
            FROM   rmart_accnum_all_divisi_2023
          ) src
          ON (src.account_num = dst.account_num)
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE
            SET divisi = src.divisi,
                segmen = src.segmen';
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.nama_tbl || ' does not exist.');
    END;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i6kU-Ehd)